# Angular generate refresh button click

Tags: html, angular

I have a button that refreshes data.

I would like to generate 10 clicks on this button.

```
<data-box class="market" [data]="data">
  <h2>Data</h2>
  <img class="refresh" src="assets/img/refresh.png" (click)="getMarketData()"/>
</data-box>
```

I want a function that clicks the button (not call the function that is triggered by the button)

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: I want to make a function that clicks the button when I want. (Not call the function that is triggered by the button)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img class="refresh" src="assets/img/refresh.png" #Refresh (click)="getMarketData()" />
```

Add #Refresh on your element, and then reference it using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('Refresh') myDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  triggerFalseClick() {
    let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
    el.click();
}
```

triggerFalseClick will click your button, you can call it as many times as you want.